# warning MSB3258 on mscorlib for shared reference

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2019, mscorlib

So I am currently working on a .NET Framework project that is referencing a DLL made by another dev I am working with that I will call "random.dll". My project is targeting .NET 3.5. I have no compiler errors in my project but when I attempt to build while referencing this DLL I receive a warning during the build saying the reference could not be resolved:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "random.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
```

This build warning causes my build to fail when attempting to reference classes in that reference.

I then zipped up my project and sent it to the dev who was able to build it themselves with no changes to the project. I am trying to figure out what could possibly be different on only my machine that would cause this issue.

Comment: The DLL you're trying to reference targets a newer version of .NET Framework than your project does. This "random.dll" will have to be recompiled to target .NET 3.5 or lower in order for you to use it.

Comment: That makes sense to me but what I don't understand is why the other dev can build my project in .NET 3.5 and I cannot. All of his projects referencing that file are also in .NET 3.5 so I can't figure out why my machine seems to be special...

Comment: That's just not possible. Maybe it's upgrading the project to 4.0 on his machine? Something is happening, but it's definitely not a 3.5 project running while referencing a 4.0 library.

Comment: So it was a little bit convoluted but short answer is the other dev is building in Linux and I am in Windows.  The random.dll is patched using a tool called MonoMod and it is pulling in these 4.0 references. For some reason the Linux machine doesn't seem to care about this but my Windows machine certainly does. We are working with the MonoMod folk to help with this but that is outside the scope of this question. I'll accept Eng's answer as that was correct, changing my framework does indeed make my issue go away.

Comment: But also @madreflection you were pretty on the nose, we will be needing random.dll to properly recompile in 3.5 before I can start using it. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your .net framework to 4.0.0

Comment: For my particular situation, I am expected to run in .NET 3.5. For wierd reasons, the random.dll is building with .NET 4.x dependencies and this is not expected. My dev friend is working in a Linux system so I guess Linux doesn't care about this? My Windows machine does.

Anyway, if my error was legitimately the problem, your solution would get me building again so I accepted it as the answer in case it helps anyone else. Thanks!